# How to create a list considering a condition in sql (azure databricks)

Tags: sql, data-analysis, azure-databricks, databricks-sql, exploratory-data-analysis

I am working on a SQL query (Azure Databricks environment), where considering the following dataset:

| clientid | visited | channel | purchase | visit_order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | abc133 | google | 0 | 1 |
| 123 | efg446 | facebook | 0 | 2 |
| 123 | gij729 | instagram | 1 | 3 |
| 456 | klm183 | google | 0 | 1 |
| 456 | nop496 | linkedin | 0 | 2 |
| 456 | qrs729 | pinterest | 1 | 3 |
| 456 | tuv894 | google | 0 | 1 |
| 456 | wyz634 | instagram | 0 | 2 |

I want to get the following output:

| clientid | user_journey | conversion |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | google, facebook, instagram | 1 |
| 456 | google, linkedin, interest | 1 |
| 456 | google, instagram | 0 |

where the **user_jorney** column is composed of the channels that participated in a conversion journey. Note that the journey of users who, until then, have not made a purchase is also built.

Looking for commands that can help with this task, I found concat_ws, where I wrote the code below:

```
select 
  clientid, 
  concat_ws(',', collect_list(channel)) as user_journey, 
  sum(purchase) as conversion
from table_name group by  clientid;
```

I get this result:

| clientid | user_journey | conversion |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | google, facebook, instagram | 1 |
| 456 | google, linkedin, pinterest, google, instagram | 1 |

Now I'm trying to consider a condition to get the desired result but so far I haven't been able to find.

Could you help me how can i solve this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I tried to repro your scenario,**

where **I gave sub query instead of original table in that query,** I am selecting original table along with one extra column as row number where I am giving row number two every row partitioned by `visit_order` column and `orderd` by visited column.

**My Query:**

```sql
select 
  clientid,
  concat_ws(',', collect_list(channel)) as user_journey, 
  sum(purchase) as conversion
from (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY visit_order ORDER BY visited) AS RowNumber FROM docs) as docstb group by clientid , RowNumber order by clientid asc
```

**Execution and Output:**

[image]